# AirPods case flashes orange and doesn’t charge

Tags: airpods

I recently bought a brand new pair of AirPods about 3 weeks ago. 2 days ago I was using them all day until they died (both the case and the AirPods). When I charge them, it blinks amber and doesn’t charge at all. I don't know if they’re broken or not.

Comment: Have you checked that air pods are properly seated in the case?

Answer (score 1):

Flashing amber light indicates that you may need to set up your AirPods again.

From the Apple Support document, [Charge your AirPods with charging case and learn about battery life](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207012).

> When you connect your Wireless Charging Case to a charger, or place it on a Qi-certified charging mat, the status light will stay on for 8 seconds. If the light flashes white, your AirPods are ready to set up with one of your devices. If the light flashes amber, you might need to [set up your AirPods](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207010) again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and managed to overcome it.

Symptoms:

- After Airpods got out of battery, it didn't reacted at all without any indication.
- When I connected it to charger, it indicated by amber blinking, but still didn't reacted to any of my actions (short-press to button, long-press)

The solution was to clean the lightning port with a needle (or something). Therefore, Airpods said to me that charging device detected, but they failed to charge properly.